# hugo 0.61 figure shortcode caption not working

Tags: markdown, hugo, hugo-shortcode

Running hugo 0.61 on a Mac for local dev installed from brew.

```
hugo version
Hugo Static Site Generator v0.61.0/extended darwin/amd64 BuildDate: unknown
```

When I use the `figure` shortcode, the `src`, `width`, and `height` attributes work, but `caption`, `title`, `link`, and `alt` don't seem to.

Code in page:

```
{{< figure src="images/rpi_up.png" link="images/rpi_up.png" width="400" height="200" alt="All 4 Raspberry Pi nodes came up cleanly on the first try" title="All 4 Raspberry Pi nodes came up cleanly on the first try" >}}
```

(the example at https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#figure seems to use `title` for `caption` - I've tried both ways)

The following HTML is rendered with no errors:

```
<div class="columns is-centered container">
    <div class="column is-full">
        <figure>
            <img class="rounded-corners" src="/work/kubernetes/kube_117_on_rpi_4/images/rpi_up_huefe7661fd5aa8ec47e26b05b16d13406_10693_400x200_resize_box_2.png" 
                width="400" 
                height="200">
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there some requirement or configuration I'm missing? I don't see anything noted in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that shortcodes were per-theme. The them I was using had a very simple shortcode that only pulled in the width and heigh attributes. I found a more complete one and modified it to suit my needs.